# One or more <div> tags fill parent <td>

Tags: html, css

I have a table that is filled dynamically. Each `<td>` could have one or more `<div class="status">` inside of it. Those status divs are colored green or red based on success or failure.

I want those divs to completely fill the parent `<td>`. Originally, I was using `height: 100%;`, but if there are multiple divs, then this is not good. However, if I remove the height selector, the entries with only one `<div>` are puny. This is seen in the picture below.

How can I ensure that these single `<td>` entries with only a single `<div>` are completely filled?

In summary, the sum total of the `<div class="status">` should fill the parent `<td>`. Thanks!

[image: divs don't fill parent td]

Here is a fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/qwseoypx/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Could you give an example of the DOM layout and your css in question?

Comment: is it possible for a cell to have green and red? or is it always all red or all green?

Comment: Should be able to use flexbox, if you do up a fiddle we can show you how.

Comment: @MattCowley I included a fiddle above that shows a simple example of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```css
tr {
  display: flex;
}
td {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.successDiv, .failureDiv {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}
.successDiv {
  background-color: green;
}

.failureDiv {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <div class="successDiv">
            Success
          </div>
      </td>
      <td>
          <div class="successDiv">
            Success
          </div>
          <div class="failureDiv">
            Failure
          </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/qwseoypx/1/

Comment: Is this really a good idea? overriding default table elements to be flex? I don't know if anything will go wrong but just looks weird

Answer (score 0):

```css
.fill {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: solid 2px black;
  padding: 0;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="fill green">
          <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet ball tip landjaeger pancetta cupim, ground round leberkas pastrami. Tongue strip steak biltong, chicken bresaola rump swine tail venison landjaeger ball tip tri-tip. Alcatra turkey ball tip cupim, beef ribs hamburger flank
            landjaeger ham hock venison tongue biltong. Corned beef frankfurter ham hock ball tip leberkas tenderloin picanha kevin. Jerky sausage strip steak jowl shankle pork belly. Pig alcatra beef ribs shankle jerky, flank tail landjaeger sirloin
            andouille bacon cow.</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="fill red">
          <p>Ham hock capicola short ribs, bacon picanha pancetta alcatra kielbasa turducken kevin leberkas short loin shank shoulder.</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="fill red">
          <p>Meatloaf tenderloin chuck rump short ribs, ball tip biltong tri-tip picanha fatback. Short ribs sirloin frankfurter swine landjaeger flank t-bone pastrami strip steak. Pancetta cupim shank turducken, picanha rump frankfurter bacon.</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This will work for what you've initially stated.
**Note:** This is very rough, but it'll suit your needs with a bit of CSS tweaking.
Hope it helps!